# Change Highlight Color After User input in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, while-loop

I have a piece of code that will allow me to find the next free cell in column F, where an operator will input a Weight.

I wanted to help by highlighting the cells in a range close to where the input needs to be done (this can help to check that the entry is correct without filtering).

I can do that with the code below but I'm trying to remove the highlighting after the cell is written and I'm failing. I tried an approach with 'Do Until' but was also not satisfactory. The code runs but it does not remove the highlight once the user adds a value.

I have also tried using Wait functions but they freeze Excel completely (I cannot modify any value). Additionally, when I run in debug and use a random iteration to modify the Cell value, my code works.

```
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column F (aka, column 6)
    ' We will add i rows to make the ith blank (in the for loop)
            PreFree = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

            NextFree = PreFree + 1

    ' Select Cell for manual input
          Range("F" & NextFree).Select


          'Do Until emptyWeight = False
          If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("F" & NextFree) = "" Then
           emptyWeight = True
             Range(Cells(NextFree, "C"), Cells(NextFree, "F")).Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
           Else
             Range(Cells(NextFree, "C"), Cells(NextFree, "F")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            emptyWeight = False
           End If
```

Comment: Does Conditional Formatting work? If a column is to be completed, and you want the next empty space, you may be able to do a Conditional Format.

Comment: I'm really trying to avoid conditional formatting at any cost.

Comment: Ah ok. Just curious, why? It wouldn't require a macro which some users may not activate or accidentally break, etc.  Anyways to change it after a cell is filled in, look in to the `Worksheet Change()` event

Answer (score 0):

As Sir BruceWayne said, you can do this with `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' Declare and prepare the intersection & union of ranges
Dim rIntersect As Range
Set rIntersect = Intersect(Target.Offset(1, 0), Sheets("YourSheet").Range("F:F"))

' Exit this event if there is no change in column f
If rIntersect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

' Include TargetCell
Set rIntersect = Union(Target, rIntersect)

' Declare the 'each range', in case the user will paste values into column f
Dim rEach As Range

' Will loop through each cell that made a change in column f
For Each rEach In rIntersect
  ' Give default color.
  rEach.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

  ' And test if the value <blank>, sets color if it is true.
  If rEach.Value = "" Then rEach.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

Hope this works for you. Good luck!

## To OP, paste your code here

[image]

Comment: For some reason this is not working. I don't know if I did not use it correctly. I got rid of most of the If statement and went to End sub. Highlighting works. Within the same form I just added the Private Sub you gave me but it doesn't remove the highlighting

Comment: Oh no! This `Sub`  should go into the `worksheet` you want the change of color to take effect. In your case it is the "Input" `Sheet`.

Comment: This code is not intended to run manually. It should be pasted in the worksheet's code under Microsoft Excel Objects.